# Is there any way to access the value from return dictionary in Scrapy?

Tags: python, scrapy

I need to save the output from parse_link method to parse method variable job_des. Then I have to save it into the items. I only have to save the value of the key that exist in the dictionary but i am getting error that it is not subscriptible. Is there any way to do so?

````
import scrapy
from ..items import ScrapcareerItem

class CarSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "car"
    start_urls = ['https://www.example.com/']
    def parse(self, response):
        items=ScrapcareerItem()
        abc = response.xpath("xpath").extract()
        for ab in abc:
            sub_car = response.xpath(xpath).extract()
            items['abc']=abc
            items['sub_car']=sub_car
            info = response.xpath("xpath")
            for link in info:
                url = response.urljoin(link.extract())
                job_des=scrapy.Request(url, callback=self.parse_link)
                yield job_des

    def parse_link(self,response):
        job_des = response.xpath("xpath").extract()
        return {'job_des':job_des}```
````

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
class CarSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "car"
    start_urls = ['https://www.example.com/']
    def parse(self, response):
        items=ScrapcareerItem()
        abc = response.xpath("xpath").extract()
        for ab in abc:
            sub_car = response.xpath(xpath).extract()
            items['abc']=abc
            items['sub_car']=sub_car
            info = response.xpath("xpath")
            for link in info:
                url = response.urljoin(link.extract())
                yield scrapy.Request(url, callback=self.parse_link)

    def parse_link(self,response):
        job_des = response.xpath("xpath").extract()
        yield {'job_des':job_des}
```

Comment: if I have to save the yield value to the items['Job_des'] then what should I do? Because I am getting the whole dictionary and I just want only the value so that I can save it to the Item['job_des'].